# Referencing string array

Tags: android, string

I have a problem that is bugging me. I created a string array in `strings.xml`which is called `bookmark_titles`. I want to use it for my alert dialog and populate a list using them, however I can't see name of my array in `R.array`, it has only those that built in android eg PhoneTypes. How do I reference my array ?

```
strings.xml
```

```
<string name="app_name">Dialogs</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string-array name="bookmark_titles">
    <item>Google</item>
    <item>Bing</item>
    <item>Gmail</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

FireMissilesDialogFragment

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Books are :");
               .setItems(R.array., new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   ---> can't see reference here
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                   // of the selected item
               }
        });
        return builder.create();

    }
```

Comment: Did you try a clean/rebuild? Can't see a reason it wouldn't show up as `R.array.bookmark_titles`.

Comment: refer it like `R.array.bookmark_titles`. more info @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. Also check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson yes I cleaned the project, same issue

Comment: @Frugo try removing `;` from `builder.setTitle("Books are :")`.

Answer (score 1):

try "array":

```
<array name="bookmark_titles">
<item>Google</item>
<item>Bing</item>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for [`setItems()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) states that:

> This should be an array type i.e. R.array.foo

Use an `array` instead of `string-array`:

```
<string name="bookmark_google">Google</string>
<string name="bookmark_bing">Bing</string>
<string name="bookmark_yahoo">Yahoo</string>

<array name="pref_values_sort_list">
    <item>@string/bookmark_google</item>
    <item>@string/bookmark_bing</item>
    <item>@string/bookmark_yahoo</item>
</array>
```

Comment: i don't think that's an issue. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray. i just tried it out with string array works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

I had to remove import.android.R, after it, it worked ! Thanks guys